90s live action adventure TV series or mini series
Looking for a 90s live action adventure TV series or mini series. I watched it on TV in the 90s (but the series may be from the 80s). It was shown during the day.
What I remember:
The setting was (or at least at some stage of the plot) a tropical island, tall ship(s), pirates or explorers and savages/natives of some sort. I remember 2 scenes:
1) a young man (teenager?) rows across a sunny bay to a tall ship moored in the distance. The ship looks unmanned and as he is trying to get it to sail (?) he gets knocked out by the boom
2) the same young man gets injured (speared in the chest) during a confrontation with the savage natives of the island but all ends well
What it is not:
Kidnapped, Treasure Island, Sandokan, Smuggler, Adventurer, Pirate Islands or Amazon (1999 series), Sindbad, Hercules the Legendary Journeys.
What it could be but I cannot confirm myself:
Sliders, Coral Island (1983). Or something entirely different.
Does anyone remember the scenes described above and could help out with the title of this series please?

I don't think it's Sliders.  I could be wrong, as I never did watch season 5, but the scenes you describe do not sound at all familiar from the first 4 seasons.
